# JavaFX NoSuchMethodError: "SequenceVariable.make"

Tags: eclipse, makefile, javafx, nosuchmethoderror

I'm having trouble getting a JavaFX Application to run, and I'm uncertain how to fix the problem. I'm using Eclipse and JavaSE 1.6

When running the application, I'm getting a NoSuchMethodError:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 
    at com.sun.javafx.runtime.Main.main(Main.java:80)
    [etc.]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.javafx.runtime.location.SequenceVariable.make(Lcom/sun/javafx/runtime/TypeInfo;)Lcom/sun/javafx/runtime/location/SequenceVariable;
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.<init>(Toolkit.fx:83)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.desktop.DesktopToolkit.<init>(DesktopToolkit.fx:9)
    [etc.]
```

However, when I examine my libraries, the SequenceVariable.class file has the following static methods listed:

```
make(TypeInfo<T, ?>)
make(TypeInfo<T, ?>, boolean, BindingExpression, DependencySource...)
make(TypeInfo<T, ?>, BindingExpression, DependencySource...)
make(TypeInfo<T, ?>, Sequence<? extends T>)
```

So I don't understand why it's claiming that the "make" method is not found. Does anyone know why I am getting this error, and how I should go about fixing it?

Thanks.

Comment: what version of javaFX you using ?

Comment: That's something I'm trying to figure out .. I don't actually know. How can I find that out? I can't find anything in the manifest file ...

Comment: huh ,you didn't installed javafx SDK manually ?

Comment: Sorry - I'm using javaFX SDK 1.2.3 ...

Comment: there you go ,install JavaFX 2.2 SDK or installa JDK 7 update 6 or later

Comment: ok, I just did that, but I have the impression that javafx 2.2 works very differently from 1.2 - is that the case? to clarify, I'm trying to get a package running which was written 2 years ago, using javafx 1.2
EDIT: actually, I see now that I have to transfer .fx files to .java ... thanks for the help in any case.